# Bounty bigger than reputation points

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties

Can you set a bounty bigger than your current rep points? (Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70780?tab=reputation))

Comment: Hmmm... I suspect this user had a bunch of questions deleted that were from early in his history. It'll take a mod to find that out.

Comment: Let me get this straight, the user got a bunch of points, then used them for bounties, then a mod deleted them so the points vanished?

Comment: He has a lot of deleted answers, but they only total about 6 points. I remember the name though; it's possible that he's had multiple accounts... or *something*.

Comment: Just to be clear, you _cannot_ offer a bounty bigger than your current number of points, right?

Comment: @cambraca: Right. However, only active posts appear in the reputation graph. So it's possible the user had an active+inactive score higher than the 300 bounty he gave.

Comment: @Jon: Where does _inactive_ score come from?

Comment: @cambraca: It's a byproduct of the denormalized rep score. Meaning, the user earned reputation from posts that were subsequently deleted. When that happens, the reputation earned is not rescinded until a moderator uses a function to recalculate the user's reputation. This is by design of the system.

Comment: @Jon: I see, but, can a moderator look at the user's entire history? If so, shouldn't Michael have been able to see more than the 6 points he mentioned?

Comment: (I'm just curious man)

Comment: @cambraca: I'm honestly not sure. This is pretty much guesswork for anyone except the dev team at this point.

Comment: This behaviour still persists. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12979601/1530938. There is a bounty of 400 points on that question and the OP currently has around 334 as at post time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's more of a bug in the rep graph you linked; a user's rep is never less than 1.

The user was able to submit a bounty that large because it was created when upvotes on questions were worth 10 points (they are 5 now) and the majority of his received upvotes are on questions.

Comment: But we'll look at fixing the rep graph :)